# thread.sleep doesn't work correctly in C# graphics

Tags: c#, delay

I want to draw a pixel and after 5 seconds draw another pixel.but in this code,after I click on the button,it takes 5 seconds and two pixels draw in the same time.it means first run thread.sleep and then set pixels.How to solve it?

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(panel1.Width, panel1.Height);
        panel1.BackgroundImage = (Image)bmp;
        panel1.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.None;

        bmp.SetPixel(15, 15, Color.Red);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        bmp.SetPixel(17, 17, Color.Red);

    }
```

Comment: Your sleep is holding up the GUI thread and stopping from redrawing. Use a timer so the GUI thread isn't held up.

Comment: Write the code into an answer Matt. It's the correct one.

Comment: The simplest way to do this is to replace `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)` with `await Task.Delay(5000)`

Comment: (not related to your current problem) You never do anything with the `Graphics` object. I would normally say you need to remember to dispose it, but you never use it so just get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are sleeping in the same UI thread. You need to use another thread for waiting and calling back to the UI to draw another pixel, etc.

The easiest way is to use WinForms Timer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use async/await not to block your UI

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(panel1.Width, panel1.Height);
    panel1.BackgroundImage = (Image)bmp;
    panel1.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.None;

    bmp.SetPixel(15, 15, Color.Red);
    await Task.Delay(5000); // <---
    bmp.SetPixel(17, 17, Color.Red);

}
```

Comment: You can remove the `Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();` it is never used. (or at least dispose it)

Comment: @HFDev here is a Delay for .Net 4.0 `Task Delay(int milliseconds)      
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    new System.Threading.Timer(_ => tcs.SetResult(null)).Change(milliseconds, -1);
    return tcs.Task;
}` then use it with **ContinueWith**

Comment: Or use the targeting pack and use `TaskEx`

Comment: @QtX I write your code in answer(.net 4.5) but that just draw a pixel in 15,15.why? how to solve it?

Comment: @HFDev It *should* draw another one at 17,17 after 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

That's because it's all happening on the same thread, when you call `Thread.Sleep` you sleep the thread so the UI doesn't get a chance to update, so the drawing all happens at once. Try delaying the second dot on another thread then draw it

```
bmp.SetPixel(15, 15, Color.Red);
Task.Delay(5000).ContinueWith(t => 
{
    bmp.SetPixel(17, 17, Color.Red);
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of comments:

- You are creating a graphics object but not doing anything with it.
- When you call Thread.Sleep you are sleeping the thread also responsible for painting your UI. This is why both pixels pop at the same time.

If you are looking for "real time" rendering of changes to a bitmap back into a winforms UI, you have a lot more work to do.

Something like:

- Create thread to manage updates to a bitmap
- Create signal mechanism from that thread back to UI thread that there are interesting things to paint
- synchronize access to the bitmap during update operation and marshal call onto the UI thread

Without more info about what you are actually trying to accomplish there isn't much advice to give you other than what has been posted here and in other answers